# Partitioning a list of Eithers in Java

Tags: java

Largely as an academic exercise, I'm experimenting with my own implementation of `Either` in Java, inspired by Haskell's `either` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html)

I have a working implementation which I'm pleased with:

```
    Either<String, Integer> either = Either.left(A_STRING);
    assertThat(either.left(), is(A_STRING));
    assertThat(either.isLeft(), is(true));
    assertThat(either.isRight(), is(false));
    assertThat(either.map(x -> AN_INTEGER, y -> A_LONG), is(Either.left(AN_INTEGER)));
    assertThat(either.consolidate(x -> A_LONG, y -> ANOTHER_LONG), is(A_LONG));
```

The equivalent of Haskell's `lefts` and `rights` is to filter a stream:

```
 Stream<String> s = streamOfEithers
     .filter(Either::isLeft)
     .map( x -> x.left())
```

The problem I'm having is in creating an equivalent of Haskell's `partitionEithers`.

My first instinct was:

```
  streamOfEithers.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Either::isLeft))
```

However this seems to lose my types -- it returns `Map<Boolean, Either<? extends Object, ? extends Object>>` rather than (for example) `Map<Boolean, Either<String,Integer>`.

Of course, ideally the result of partitioning is not two lists of `Eithers` but two lists, one of each type. Java doesn't have a `Pair<T,U>` class, but if it did, perhaps:

```
 List<Either<String,Integer>> listOfEithers = ...
 Pair<List<String>,List<Integer>> partitioned = Either.partitionList(listOfEithers);
```

Otherwise, the best I have managed is:

```
 Map<Boolean, Either<String,Integer>> partitioned = Either.partitionList(listOfEithers);
```

... which is not a very convenient structure for a client.

Other than writing a `Pair`, or using a `Pair` from some collections library (Guava, incidentally, refuses to provide `Pair` as it "does more harm than good"), how can I best provide an equivalent to Haskell's `partitionEithers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own aggregate type for this, in place of `Pair`, specifically tailored to `Either`, which has a collector to go along with it. Here is a simplified implementation:

```
class Aggregate<T, U> {
    List<T> tList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<U> uList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Either<T, U> e) {
        if(e.isLeft()) {
            tList.add(e.left());
        } else {
            uList.add(e.right());
        }
    }

    public Aggregate<T, U> combine(Aggregate<T, U> other) {
        tList.addAll(other.tList);
        uList.addAll(other.uList);
        return this; // could create a new Aggregate here instead...
    }

    public static <T, U> Collector<Either<T,U>, ? , Aggregate<T, U>> partitionEithers() {
        return Collector.of(Aggregate::new, Aggregate::add, Aggregate::combine);
    }
}
```

Then the result becomes:

```
Aggregate<String, Integer> result = streamOfEithers.collect(Aggregate.partitionEithers());
```

Comment: Accepted this as it comes to the same conclusion as I did - a custom type is needed - I went for `PartitionedEithers<L,R>` and made it immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Either<Integer, String>>> collect = list.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Either::isLeft));
```

Assuming that your Either implementation's generic type signature is `Either<L,R>` (which is what I've tested with example implementation), there should be no problem with type erasure, and it will compile as expected.

After that, you can initialize your `Pair` like this:

```
Pair<List<Integer>, List<String>> result =
      pair(
          collect.getOrDefault(true, Collections.emptyList()).stream().map(Either::left).collect(toList()),
          collect.getOrDefault(false, Collections.emptyList()).stream().map(Either::right).collect(toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Haskell so I cannot provide a full answer to the question.

I do however know a bit about Java generics. The issue with

`streamOfEithers.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Either::isLeft))`

returning `Map<Boolean, Either<? extends Object, ? extends Object>>`

is because of type erasure. Simply put, java generics are much weaker than the same type of logic in many other languages (eg. templates in C++). [Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2025637&seqNum=8) is a more detailed explanation of what generics can and can't do. If you would like to dig really deep I would suggest looking [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).